How output single quote in dbt post hook macros with jinja?
Here is post hook for dbt model:
{{
  config(
    post_hook=[
      '{{ execute_if_exists("delete from " ~ this ~ " where day = date('' " ~ var("mydatevar") ~ " '')")  }}',
    ]
  )
}}

Please note the '' in the string. Next:
{% macro execute_if_exists(query) -%}
    {{ query }}
{%- endmacro %}

And I got
delete from catalog.myschema.mytable where day = date( 2024-10-02 )

While expected is:
delete from catalog.myschema.mytable where day = date(' 2024-10-02 ')    

I have tried \' and got error. I have switched " and ' again no effect.
UPDATED

'{{ execute_if_exists("delete from " ~ this ~ " where day = date(' " ~ var("mydatevar") ~ " ')")  }} - compilation error
"{{ execute_if_exists('delete from ' ~ this ~ ' where day = date(' ' ~ var('mydatevar') ~ ' ')')  }}" - same effect
"{{ execute_if_exists('delete from ' ~ this ~ ' where day = date(' ' ~ var('mydatevar') ~ ' ')')  }}" - also compilation error


Have you tried with just one single quote character rather than two?

'{{ execute_if_exists("delete from " ~ this ~ " where day = date(' " ~ var("mydatevar") ~ " ')")  }}' - leads to compilation error

I do not have a setup where I can actually test this, but how about splitting the quotes out and trying to concatenate them like so:   '{{ execute_if_exists("delete from " ~ this ~ " where day = date(" ~ "'" ~ var("mydatevar") ~ "'" ~ ")")  }}'. Note, it would help when reporting problems that you also provide the complete text of the error messages that you see.

In that case I will a string '{{.... "'. I mean that ' will connect with leading quote. That why escaping is needed.

I have been working on Jinja but cannot find a way to create what you want. I guess you need input from someone with more experience. You could also try the Jinja issue tracking system.

I just cam across a similar issua at https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5388872/Python-flash-code-show-error-expected where the suggestion is to use the &apos; escape sequence to insert a single quote.

I created a test locally replicating your use case, and the below worked:
'{{ execute_if_exists("delete from " ~ this ~ " where day = date(" ~ "'" ~ var("mydatevar") ~ "'" ~ ")")  }}'
I am basically adding some extra steps to create the single quotes effectively, and concatenating them

I tried that yesterday but could not get it to work. Are you using a newer version of Jinja?

I am using dbt-core's Jinja2 version
